# Interface Function Call on GoLang

Tags: go, interface

I am having a problem go interfaces.

Here is my main.go file;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bitbucket.org/xyz/trash/a"
)

// Second -
type Second interface {
    Area() float64
}

// Area -
func Area() float64 {
    return 2
}


func main() {

    r := new(a.Rect)

    n := new(Second)

    r.F = *n

    fmt.Println(r.Area()) 

}
```

And my other package, a.go;

```
package a

// First -
type First interface {
    Area() float64
}

// Rect -
type Rect struct {
    F First 
}

// Area -
func (r Rect) Area() float64 {
    return 1
}
```

I am expecting this line

fmt.Println(r.Area())

to print "2", not "1". What am i missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding of what interfaces are. In go, a type implements an interface if it implements the function defined for the interface. So, in your code, interfaces `a.First` and `main.Second` are **equivalent**. A type implements both of them or none at all.

So, the type `Rect` is both a `a.First` and a `main.Second`. The field F inside Rect means that it contains another type that implements First (or Second because they are the same).

When you call `r.Area()`, go executes the function `func (r Rect) Area() uint64`. With the line `r.F = *n`, you assign the interface Second to First (they are equivalent, no problem). However, if you try to call `r.F.Area()` it will panic because F is not a type that implements First, it *is* First.

So, you should create another type which implements First then assign it to r. Then you can call `r.F.Area()`.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. Actually what i am trying to achive is, making "r" to have my new interface (n). Not calling a global function.

Comment: You already implemented the interface for Rect, you cannot change it. I elaborated my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

First, look at your code again. As written, `a.Rect.Area()` returns 1. It always returns 1. Set all the properties you like. It returns 1. Gnash your teeth and curse the gods. It returns 1. Because it's a function that returns 1. That's what it does.

Write it like this:

```
// Area -
func (r Rect) Area() float64 {
    return r.F.Area()
}
```

...and you'll panic because you've got another issue.

`Area()` in main.go doesn't have a receiver. It has nothing to do with interfaces. It's just a function. No objects. No implementing anything. No polymorphism. No nothing.

You've declared `n` as a pointer to an interface, not an implementation of an interface. It's nil. If you try to dereference it the whole world will come crashing down into the void.

If you want to be able to call `n.Area()` then make `Second` a concrete type.

(In main.go)

```
// Second -
type Second struct {}

// Area -
func (s Second) Area() float64 {
    return 2
}
```

Do you see the difference? Second is now a `struct` that *implements* the interface `a.First` because it is the receiver of an appropriate `Area()` method. Thus you will get the expected behavior.